# Infinity Loop in Lexical Analyzer in C++

Tags: c++

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ifstream inFile;
    int numOfLines = 0, numOfTokens = 0, numOfStrings = 0, maxStringLength = 0, l = 0, fileCount=0, mostCommonCount=0;
    string inputFile, mostCommonList="", word;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if(strpbrk(argv[i] , "-")){
            if(flags.find(string(argv[i]))!=flags.end()) flags[string(argv[i])] = true;
            else{
                cerr << "INVALID FLAG " << argv[i] << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else{
            inFile.open(argv[i]);
            fileCount++;
            if(!inFile && fileCount==1){
                cerr << "UNABLE TO OPEN " << argv[i] << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            else{
                string line;
                while(getline(inFile, line)) inputFile+=line+='\n';
                if(fileCount>1){
                    cerr << "TOO MANY FILE NAMES" << endl;
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int linenum = 0;
    TType tt;
    Token tok;
    while((tok = getNextToken(&inFile, &linenum))!=DONE && tok != ERR){
        tt = tok.GetTokenType();
        word = tok.GetLexeme();
        if(flags["-v"]==true){
            (tt == ICONST||tt==SCONST||tt==IDENT) ? cout<<enumTypes[tok.GetTokenType()]<<"("<< tok.GetLexeme()<<")"<<endl : cout<< enumTypes[tok.GetTokenType()]<<endl;
        }
        if(flags["-mci"]==true){
            if(tt==IDENT){
                (identMap.find(word)!=identMap.end()) ? identMap[word]++ : identMap[word]=1;
                if(identMap[word]>mostCommonCount) mostCommonCount = identMap[word];
            }
        }
        if(flags["-sum"]==true){
            numOfTokens++;
            if(tt==SCONST){
                numOfStrings++;
                l = word.length();
                if(l > maxStringLength) maxStringLength = l;
            }
        }
    }
    if(tok==ERR){
        cout << "Error on line" << tok.GetLinenum()<<"("<<tok.GetLexeme()<<")"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if(flags["-mci"]==true){
        cout << "Most Common Identifier: ";
        if(!identMap.empty()){
            word ="";
            for(auto const& it : identMap){
                if(it.second==mostCommonCount) word += it.first + ",";
            }
            word.pop_back();
            cout << word << endl;
        }
    }
    if(flags["-sum"]){
        numOfLines = tok.GetLinenum();
        numOfLines = tok.GetLinenum();
        cout << "Total lines: " << numOfLines << endl;
        cout << "Total tokens: " << numOfTokens << endl;
        cout << "Total strings: " << numOfStrings << endl;
        cout << "Length of longest string: " << maxStringLength << endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason this code is running infinitely. I cannot figure out the source of error. I also do not know whether this file or the other linked file is causing this error so I posted the main program code. I think is one of the switch statements that causing this error but I am not sure. FYI: I am supposed to make a lexical analyzer so I had three files one lexigh.h (contains all the data types and all the functions), getToken.cpp(file that defines the functions from lexigh.h) and the main program which calls the methods and tests it.

Comment: What does `getNextToken` return when it fails to read from the stream? I ask because you pass to it a stream that has already reached end-of-file, by way of `while(getline(inFile, line))` loop.

Comment: Use your debugger and you'll find out quick enough.